# Was a study published about some linguists who taught their children only a constructed language?

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition, constructed-language

I heard a myth that group of linguists made an experiment with their own children and taught them only a artificial language (in that myth it was a loglan), but if it was true a scientific paper would be presented. The most close paper I found was this one http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0749596X90900544 In this experiment children were taught small languages and were old enough for knowledge of some other native language. Another similar case is G. Soros, he is native speaker of Esperanto.

My question is: was this (or similar) study real?

Comment: Very interesting indeed! My understanding is that Soros is not unique -- as the language and the community is big and growing, more and more esperantistoj are native speakers.